# Unity 3D 2017 MAC debug Visual Studio 2017

Tags: macos, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have mac system with Unity 3D 2017.2 installed, and I also installed Parallel Desktop with Windows 7 operating system, in Windows 7 system installed Visual Studio 2017 v15.4.2

Is it possible to debug my Unity 2017 from Visual Studio 2017?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actualy visual studio tool for unity, wich use Remote Debugger, support only remote debug for another windows : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp

If you want to have visual studio on your MAC you could install it : https://www.visualstudio.com/fr/vs/visual-studio-mac/

and configure Unity to use vs as your default editor/debugger https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/05/10/unity-game-development-with-visual-studio-for-mac/